# C# method error when calling it

Tags: c#

I have a assignment for my C# course, but I cant figure it out.
I want to show the cars I have, but it doesn't work.
Can someone please help me ?

Program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace auto
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<auto> autos = new List<auto>();
            auto auto1 = new auto("Lamborgini" , "Aventador" , "2004");
            display();
        }

          void display(List<auto> auto)
        {
            foreach (auto item in auto)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Merk :" + item.merk );
                Console.WriteLine("Model :" + item.model);
                Console.WriteLine("Jaar :" + item.jaar);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace auto
{
    class auto
    {

        public string merk { get; set; }
        public string model { get; set; }
        public string jaar { get; set; }

        public auto(string merk , string model, string jaar)
        {
            this.merk = merk;
            this.model = model;
            this.jaar = jaar;
        }




    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'auto' of 'Program.display(List)'    auto    C:\Users\nickg\source\repos\auto\auto\Program.cs    14  Active

Comment: Because you are not passing the parameter in the function call `display()`

Comment: can you please tell me what to do then ?

Comment: Just pass the parameter. `display(autos);`

Comment: still getting this error : Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Program.display(List<auto>)' auto C:\Users\nickg\source\repos\auto\auto\Program.cs 14 Active

Comment: Try to search for the error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property" on google you will easily find the answer. As a developer, you should learn how to interpret the error messages. Most of the time they contain the answer you are looking for.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [C# Naming Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines)

Answer (score 1):

You are going to get a compilation error. So all you need to do is pass the parameter to the function.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<auto> autos = new List<auto>();
        autos.Add(new auto("Lamborgini" , "Aventador" , "2004"));
        display(autos);
    }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that even after doing this your list will come up empty since you never added anything to it.

Comment: hey thanks for replying but i still get this error : Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Program.display(List<auto>)' auto C:\Users\nickg\source\repos\auto\auto\Program.cs 14 Active

Comment: alright thanks , that what my next question is. how do i do that. im sorry for the many question but i just started oop.

Answer (score 0):

Make the display method static and pass `autos` as the parameter when you call it.

The posted code uses `auto` as the namespace, class name and parameter name, so I suspect sooner or later the compiler will get confused. Consider giving them different names.

Comment: alright thanks for the tip. This did fix my problem altough my functions doesnt work good. it just opens and closes. the class doesnt get filled.... any ideas ?

Comment: @NickGlas Did you make this change `autos.Add(new auto("Lamborgini" , "Aventador" , "2004"));` You need to add the object to the list.

Comment: @NickGlas Before calling display, do `autos.Add(auto1);`. Also you may want to move the ReadKey outside the loop, so that it stops at the end of the list rather than after each car. That way if there is nothing in the list it will still stop.

Comment: @NickGlas Excellent. You can mark this as the accepted answer by pressing the tick to the left of it. And if the information was helpful, you can upvote things. Neither of these things cost you anything.